# Как добавить вертикальный скролл в splitContainer

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть splitContainer, в Panel1 я добавил элемент Panel в котором в событии Paint отрисовываю изображение

```
 private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (img != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0.0f, 0.0f, (float)y, (float)x);

            }
        }
```

но как мне сделать так, чтобы появился вертикальный скроллбар? я как только не прописывал

```
panel1.AutoScroll = true;
splitContainer1.Panel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

но это не помогает, когда (float)y, (float)x большие картинка просто уходит из зоны видимости и скролл не появляться. Может кто помочь?

Comment: Автоскролл должен быть установлен у `splitContainer1.Panel1`. Тогда она будет реагировать на изменение размеров _вложенных_ в неё контролов. А вот размер `panel` нужно изменять вручную, т. к. отрисовка в графиксе не вызывает событий изменения размера и т. п.

Comment: В событии `Pain` добавьте что-то вроде: `panel1.Size = new Size(y, x);`

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло